# How to Unlock Samsung Galaxy s21 ultra with totally dead screen?

Tags: lock-screens, broken-screen, external-keyboard, mouse, samsung-galaxy-s-21

My screen stopped working. Both display, and touch. I can connect it to a dongle with HDMI and USB ports.I get the display out, as seen below. When I connect mouse or keyboard, I get the "device connected" sound. But no matter what I press, drag or click, it doesn't seem to make a difference, phone stays locked.

I didn't have an option to unlock my phone using accounts.samsung.com enabled on that device, something I regret, but can't fix now.

If it matters, I unlock using the symbol method. I have a face unlock enabled, too, but I lost about 23kg / 50lbs and it stopped to recognize my face. I was "just about to" re-record it. Another thing I should've done to save me from being in this situation, but didn't and can't fix now.

I need to unlock it in order to migrate Google Authenticator and Signal to my new phone. It can only be done with QR code. I would also gladly retrieve newest messages, but only the Authenticator and Signal are things that I would be seriously inconvenienced loosing, everything else I have backed up in more than one place already, or is not that important.

[image: Photo that shows the lock screen]

Comment: What type of lock screen protection do you use? If you have PIN/password you may be able to type in blindly on a connected USB keyboard without screen: RETURN PIN RETURN.

Comment: As I wrote, I use symbol.  The one that you draw on 3×3 dot mayrix.

Answer (score 0):

I tried connecting a wireless mouse into my S23 Ultra using a USB Type A to Type C Converter (OTG) with a Screen Locked enabled (PIN) and it worked just fine. It's weird seeing yours won't at least wake up the phone from sleep/screen-off state. Even just connecting a USB DAC to my phone does wake my phone on.

In my experience, some phone (my old OnePlus One) disable waking up the phone using a mouse that is connected with an OTG, it just stays locked until I unlocked it, unplugging and plugging the OTG back in, then it start working. I'm not sure about your S21 Ultra, but it should be the same as my S23 Ultra too.

Have you tried using other mouse or other OTG/Converter?